# pipenv and bash aliases

Tags: python, bash, pipenv

I have a core set of bash aliases defined in my `.bash_profile` (Mac). But when I activate a pipenv with `pipenv shell`, my aliases don't work and the bash `alias` command returns nothing.

Is there a configuration step needed to spawn pipenv shells that inherit bash aliases from the parent shell?

Comment: source your `.bash_profile` in the new shell? there is also an optional `.env` file to load environment...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Aliases are never inherited. `.bash_profile` is only sourced for login shells, and `pipenv` apparently creates a nonlogin interactive shell. Aliases should be defined in `.bashrc`, and on a Mac (where terminal emulators starts login shells by default), add `[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && source ~/.bashrc` to the end of your `.bash_profile`.

Comment: More detailed information about @chepner answer: https://scriptingosx.com/2017/04/about-bash_profile-and-bashrc-on-macos/

Comment: Is this answer still up to date? My `.bashrc` is practically empty but it seems that `pipevn shell` is still sourcing `.bash_profile`