# on macos "pipenv shell" => bash: update_terminal_cwd: command not found

Tags: pipenv

Trying to get pipenv working on macos 10.14.4.

```
$cat Pipfile
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
numpy = "==1.14.1"

[requires]
python_version = "3.6.8"
```

This works:

```
 $pipenv --rm
Removing virtualenv (/Users/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/blah-zeMrhw5d)…
```

This works:

```
 $pipenv install
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Pipfile: /Users/me/mypath/Pipfile
Using /Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/bin/python3 (3.6.8) to create virtualenv…
⠏ Creating virtual environment...Using base prefix '/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8'
New python executable in /Users/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/blah-zeMrhw5d/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /Users/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/blah-zeMrhw5d/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
Running virtualenv with interpreter /Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/bin/python3

✔ Successfully created virtual environment! 
Virtualenv location: /Users/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/blah-zeMrhw5d
Pipfile.lock (7fd81f) out of date, updating to (89a067)…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
✔ Success! 
Updated Pipfile.lock (7fd81f)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (7fd81f)…
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 1/1 — 00:00:02
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
```

This does NOT work:

```
$pipenv shell
Launching subshell in virtual environment…
 . /Users/alexryan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cabin_monitoring-zeMrhw5d/bin/activate
bash: update_terminal_cwd: command not found
$ . /Users/alexryan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cabin_monitoring-zeMrhw5d/bin/activate
bash: update_terminal_cwd: command not found
(cabin_monitoring) $
```

These errors get thrown every time I issue a command in this environment.

```
(blah)  >ls -lF
total 12
-rw-r--r--  1 alexryan staff  159 Apr 30 14:49 Pipfile
-rw-r--r--  1 alexryan staff 2683 Apr 30 14:50 Pipfile.lock
...
bash: update_terminal_cwd: command not found
(blah) $
(cabin_monitoring)  >
```

from https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/139808/91429 I see that `update_terminal_cwd` is defined `/etc/bashrc`

I can `source /etc/bashrc` to make this error go away, but doing so messes up my prompt so that it is no longer obvious that I am inside the virtual environment.

```
(blah) $source /etc/bashrc
hostname:blah me$
```

What is the best way to ensure that `pipenv shell` works correctly on macos?

**UPDATE**

I'm using pyenv to specify the version of python I wish to use because pipenv seems to require this.

I installed pyenv via `curl https://pyenv.run | bash` and added these lines to `~/.bashrc` as requested:

```
# Load pyenv automatically by adding
# the following to ~/.bashrc:

export PATH="/Users/me/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

And made sure that `~/.bashrc` was being called from `~/.bash_profile` like so (because apparently `pipenv shell` [is a nonlogin shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46416282/2341218)).

```
[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && source ~/.bashrc
```

pyenv is working fine with multiple versions of python installed.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of `update_terminal_cwd: command not found` error, it is sufficient to add this line to your `$HOME/.bashrc`:

```
[ -r "/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM" ] && . "/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM"
```

That loads the `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal` script which defines the `update_terminal_cwd` command, without changing your prompt or anything else.

The one other thing it does do, is configure saving the shell history in `$HOME/.bash_sessions`. If you don't want that in inferior shells, you can add before that line:

```
export SHELL_SESSION_DID_INIT=1
```